# Second axis for Pandas boxplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a side-by-side boxplot like this

```
second_axis = {0:'a',1: 'b', 2: 'c'}

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
group = np.array([  np.random.binomial(2,0.4)   for _ in range(100)])
data = [  np.random.uniform(0,5)   for _ in range(len(group))]
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data, 'group': group} )
df.boxplot(by='group', vert=False)
```

I am trying to add the 2nd vertical axis to the plot, my desired output is something like this:

[image]

I wonder whether there is a way to do this with pandas/matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [`secondary_yaxis`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/secondary_axis.html) with the identity transformation (not to be confused with [`twinx()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html) which creates a new independent y-axis and is much trickier). Note that internally, the boxplots are numbered starting from 1.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

group = np.array([np.random.binomial(2, 0.4) for _ in range(100)])
data = [np.random.uniform(0, 5) for _ in range(len(group))]
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data, 'group': group})
ax = df.boxplot(by='group', vert=False)
sec_ax = ax.secondary_yaxis('right')
second_axis = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
sec_ax.set_yticks(range(1, 1 + len(second_axis)), second_axis.values())
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: matplotlib secondary yaxis]

PS: If the groups are non-successive numbers, you can use:

```py
sec_ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks(), [second_axis[int(label.get_text())] for label in ax.get_yticklabels()])
```

or when they are strings:

```py
sec_ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks(), [second_axis[label.get_text()] for label in ax.get_yticklabels()])
```